# How to use regex to scan for lines of code that define static variable with initial capital carmel case names in .c files?

Tags: regex, perl

I am using regex to automatically enforce coding style in the code base during code review. I am having trouble to come up with the regex to scan for static variables and function names that begin with capital letter in .c files, since the scan patterns are pretty complex and dynamic, i.e., between 'static' and the variable name, there could be data type such as int, and keyword such as const.

My current solution looks like this:

```
^\s*static\s((const|inline|volatile)\s)?(unsigned\s)?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\s\*?[A-Z].*$
```

It works pretty well for many patterns, but it has false positives when data type also starts with capital letter. For example, it would be positive for 'static volatile Data_type variableName' even though 'variableName' starts with lower case.

Also some examples here:

```
   /* positives */
static void ZVar_Able(void)
static void Variable
static const int_64 Variable
static MyDataType_t DefinedVariable =
static const unsigned int INIT_VARIABLE = someValue;
static void GivenVariable(uint32_t para)
static __attribute__ ((naked)) void Function(int_64 param)
static void Var_Var_var_var(void)


/* negatives */
static const char hex[] = "000000"
static uint8_t variableHandler(uint32_t argc, char **argv)
static volatile Data_type variable
static void variable
static int *variable
static char *variablename = "just a name";
static inline void variable_enable(void)
static volatile bool_t variableIsVariable;
  static const Variabletype_t definedVariable =
```

Any ideas or alternatives would be very helpful! Thanks in advance!

Comment: your regex don't even match what you stated as positive.

Comment: @CodeManiac Sorry fix now. Copied it from my Trello board and it removed the asterisks because of its markdown formatting :\

Comment: So you just want if the variable name start with capital letters. right ?

Comment: No I want the variable names start with lowercase.

Comment: check this https://regex101.com/r/u364yG/1

Comment: @CodeManiac Ok I was trying to say I want to catch for those start with capital letters and fail those, and I want variable names start with lowercase in my code.

Comment: well this is what i asked in my previous comment. check this one https://regex101.com/r/u364yG/3

Comment: @CodeManiac wow looks like it works well, I will test it on more code

Answer (score 2):

**You can try this mate**

```
^\s*static\s(?:(const|inline|volatile|void)\s)?(unsigned\s)?([A-Za-z_]\w+\s[A-Z]\w+)$
```

> Explanation

- `^` - Matches start of string.
- `\s*` - Matches space zero or more times.
- `static\s?` - Matches `static` or `static`.
- `(?:(const|inline|volatile|void)\s)?` - Matches `const` or `inline` or `volatile` or `void` followed by a space.(? makes it optional).
- `(unsigned\s)?` - Matches `unsigned`.
- `([A-Za-z_]\w+\s[A-Z]\w+)` - Matches anything start with a letter followed by one or more word character followed by space followed by a capital letter followed by one or more character.
- `$` - End of string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/u364yG/6)

Comment: should have given some actual examples in the question, it doesn't work on real lines of code, see my edited examples above

Answer (score 1):

I have just updated your existing Regular Expression,

```
^\s*static\s((const|inline|volatile)\s)?(unsigned\s)?[a-zA-Z_][\w]+\s\*?[a-zA-Z_][\w]+$
```

Comment: This answer would be more valuable if you explained *what* you changed and *why*.

Comment: It doesn't work if you test on my edited examples above